# Unit testing with Flask + Nose (with Coverage plugin) - Views are never called according to coverage report

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, code-coverage, nose

Given the following Flask view

```
@contact.route('/contactInfo', methods=["POST"])
def contact_info():
    return Response(httplib.OK)
```

And the following trivial unit test:

```
class TestContactViews(object):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

    def post_contact_info(self):
        r_view = self.cient.post('/contactInfo')
        assert_equals(r_view, httplib.OK)
```

When running `nosetests --with-coverage --cover-tests`, the report state for the view is marked as Missing as it was never called. Is there something missing or an option that is needed ?

Note: Full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Ketouem/py-showcase)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the `-v` (verbose) option to the nosetests command, you are going to find out that many of your tests are not being found and executed. Only five tests are running.

The reason is that the methods that have unit tests need to have a name that starts with the `test_` prefix. This is how nose finds them. So basically you need to change your test to:

```
def test_post_contact_info(self):
    r_view = self.cient.post('/contactInfo')
    assert_equals(r_view, httplib.OK)
```

I also recommend that you add `--cover-package=py_showcase` to your nose command, so that the coverage is filtered to only show your own code, not the third party code that you have in your virtualenv.

Comment: I completely forgot about the `test_` prefix, I guess it was one of those 'duh!' moment ;-) Thanks !